# Why is the maven project info reports plugin creating a superfluous folder?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

When I run mvn site, the maven-project-info-reports-plugin is creating a folder in my project base folder called "${project.basedir}". My plugin is defined like so with no extra configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.maven-project-info-reports-plugin}</version>
</plugin>
```

When this happens, the site generation gives me a warning:

```
[WARNING] The repository url 'file://${project.basedir}' is invalid - 
Repository 'studio.repository' will be blacklisted.
```

Why is this oddly-named folder being created, and how can I prevent it from being created? What other configuration can I look at that might be related to this plugin?

UPDATE (the plugin is version 2.2, the latest as far as I know as of this writing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a (dated) [discussion](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/RE-Site-generation-td129243.html) in maven mailing list which looks related.  The issue seems to be due to using repository mirrors.

You would want to try with the latest version of the plugin, as well as the workaround suggested, which is to set `<dependencyLocationEnabled>` to `false`.

Comment: The suggested workaround is to *downgrade* to 2.0 as well as setting dependencyLocationEnabled to false. I downgraded from 2.2 (the latest) to 2.0 and set that configuration, and am not seeing the issue now.